# How to get input value on custom filter at Logstash

Tags: python, filter, logstash

I'm trying Logstash and so far, seems like a great tool, but I reached a point where I needed to write a custom Filter, in Python, and I'm struggling to get the input value. There follows my logstash.conf

```
input {
    stomp {
        destination => "/topic/myevents"
        host => "rabbitmq"
        password => "guest"
        user => "guest"
        vhost => "/"
        debug => true
        port => 61613
     }
}

filter {
    ruby {
        code => 'require "open3"
                 cmd = "/bin/events_filter.py {input should go here}"
                 stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3(cmd)
                ' 
    }
}

output {
    file {
        path => "~/events.txt" 
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? And if you have any tips or better  ways of calling external filters, I would love to know.

Comment: Sorry, there's a indentation problem in the ruby filter (fixed). What I want to do is simple get the value of the event capture in the stomp topic and, break it (its encrypted), normalize it and store it in a file.

Comment: If your input is working, then it's the decryption part you're trying to do in ruby?  Google for ruby code to decrypt whatever system was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow,

apparently, Logstash creates a event object that can be accessed by my ruby code (that will used as argument to my python code).

```
cmd = "/bin/events_filter.py #{event}"
```

With that, I'm able to access the input event from my Python script! =D

Comment: I hope events are rare.  Running a shell for every one could prove to have really horrible performance.

Comment: Not so rare, but it the filter is performing fairly well. I'm gonna try pushing a bit more to see how is gonna perform with 150% of regular events load.